# Monitoring HTTP requests and responses (no web browser)

Tags: web-services, http, tomcat, response, monitoring

I'm creating web services to make an Android app talk to a server.
I'm using Tomcat for the server and a JAX RS lib to convert data between Java objects and JSON during the transfers.
What I want is to be able to view the actual HTTP requests and responses the framework is creating.

A web browser (like Firefox with Firebug) won't do because I also need to check the request bodies generated by the Android app.

With the Servlet API I could intercept and get the request data with a filter, but not the response (I believe) after it was written by the framework.

Wireshark might be a solution (I'm trying it right now), but seems to be a bit to much. I need to worry about properly filtering my messages and didn't figure out yet how to get my HTTP messages properly formatted (plain text w/o the hexa content).

I wonder if there is a simpler way to do this from inside my application or from tomcat.

Comment: Tcp tunnels, such as [this one](http://www.vakuumverpackt.de/tcptunnel/) work pretty well for monitoring requests and responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Wireshark with the following filter:

> http.content_type == "application/json" || http.accept ==
>   "application/json"

To get the content decoded, right click on the json part of you package ("JavaScript Object Notation: application/json") > Copy > Bytes > Printable text only

Answer (score 0):

Try Tomcat's [AccessLogValve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve). You can configure it to log incoming request headers as well as outgoing response headers. Here's an example:

```
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_headers_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%t &quot;%r&quot; %s ||| %{Content-Length}o ||| %{User-Agent}i" />
```

Notice the %{xxx}o pattern - that's for response header. You might want to use it as %{X-JSON}o. Also notice the %{xxx}i pattern - that's for request headers.

Nest the `<Valve/>` element within a `<Context/>`, `<Host/>` or `<Engine/>` elements and you'll be all set.